# Japanese Book - "When all the cats in the world had died"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, books

I'm trying to find a Japanese book titled something like "When all the cats in the world had died" (translation may be inaccurate). I tried Googling that English title-- no luck.

**The story is about a man awaiting his death. The devil offers him one extra day to live, for each important thing he gives up doing everyday.**

The book was most probably **published in 2013, is a short story and the cover image is grey colored with a cat picture on it**.

Comment: How old is it? Has it been translated into English, or did you read it in Japanese? Is it a full length novel or a shorter story? Anything else you remember about the story or any names of characters?

Comment: I haven't read the book, I saw a Japanese architect(whose name I don't remember) talk about it at NHK Channel. The book was published in 2013, short story most probably. I will add these info to question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With judicious use of Google Translate and Amazon Japan, I believe I've found your book.

世界から猫が消えたなら "If cats disappeared from the world"

川村 元気: *Kawamura Genki*

More info [on Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E5%B7%9D%E6%9D%91-%E5%85%83%E6%B0%97/e/B00A7LUCD2/ref=ntt_athr_dp_pel_1). In case the link doesn't work, copying and pasting it into [Amazon Japan](https://www.amazon.co.jp)'s search box should work:

```
https://www.amazon.co.jp/川村-元気/e/B00A7LUCD2/ref=ntt_athr_dp_pel_1
```

The cover fits (cat peering over a wall, gray-toned) and it was published in late 2012:

[image: Book cover, gray cat partially hidden by a wall]

Comment: fanatic or fantastic?

Comment: @Zikato I'll accept either!

Answer (score 4):

**If A Cat Disappears From The World** also known as *[Sekai kara Neko ga Kieta nara](https://asianwiki.com/If_A_Cat_Disappears_From_The_World)* is a live-action movie that will be shown in Japan in 2016 starring [Takeru Satô](https://variety.com/2015/film/asia/hk-filmart-toho-shows-claws-with-internet-fantasy-novel-adaptation-cats-1201457919/).

[Takeru Satô](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takeru_Satoh) is a Japanese actor best known for playing the role of Himura Kenshin in the Rurouni Kenshin live-adaptation film and its sequels.

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4042994/):

> Young mailman finds out he has no time left due to a terminal disease. Suddenly he is approached by a devil that offers him to live more time if he eliminates something from the world. Young mailman then thinks about his relationship with friends, ex-partners, family.

Comment: Thanks Hana, I've seen rurouni kenshin, It's based on an action manga I believe. It was good. Glad this is also being made into a movie.